# Headlamp issue on buick

Tags: headlight, buick, lacrosse

I have a 2006 Buick lacrosse, I was told that both headlights went out on the drivers side, low beams and high beams

I removed the locking straps to headlight, changed the bulbs. Reinstalled the straps and only the high beams came on. So I removed the bulbs and tested for power at the harness: the high beams had around 12 volts, but the low beams were all over the place like it could get a reading.

I checked the fuse box, both left and right high and low beams were good. What should I check next. I didn't bother to check the relay for the lights because the right side low and high beams worked fine.

Comment: Check the condition of the cable and terminal - that low beam cable may have been damaged - anywhere between the fuse and headlamp...

Comment: Could the relay for the headlamps malfunctioned and only allowed one side to come on, or do they not work like that

Comment: If you have separate relays for each side... but you suggested that the relay was fine... So, now we get to it - how did you check the fuses?  Visually or with a meter? They can look good but be broken...

Comment: I visually checked both low beam fuses and both high beam fuses, then I tested them with a multimeter, 3 were reading 31.2 volts and one wasn't getting any voltage... I can't inspect the relay because there's not a similar one in the fuse box, but the right side low beams go out when I pull it out of its connection

Comment: Check what I suggested then. I took at face value what you put in your question...

Comment: I checked what you suggested, yesterday I didn't have a good ground that's why it was 30+ volts, and today I fiddled with the fuses and it got power again, but the problem was at the headlamp itself, on 2008 Buick Lacrosse they have a 3rd connecter plug on the bottom of the headlamp unit, one of the contacts got wet and broke off, there was no continuity between the light bulbs plug and the 3rd plug that went to the bottom of the headlamp unit. Thanks for the suggestion